# T3 App `❌ Invalid environment variables:`

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, trpc.io, t3

I'm using the T3-app (nextjs, tRPC, etc), and I don't know if these env variable errors just happened, or if I haven't noticed them before. However, I have all of the environment variables set in the `.env` file and have the following configuration set in the `schema.mjs` file:

```
export const serverSchema = z.object({
    DATABASE_URL: z.string().url(),
    NODE_ENV: z.enum(["development", "test", "production"]),
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET: z.string(),
    NEXTAUTH_URL: z.preprocess(
        // This makes Vercel deployments not fail if you don't set NEXTAUTH_URL
        // Since NextAuth automatically uses the VERCEL_URL if present.
        (str) => process.env.VERCEL_URL ?? str,
        // VERCEL_URL doesnt include `https` so it cant be validated as a URL
        process.env.VERCEL ? z.string() : z.string().url(),
    ),
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: z.string(),
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: z.string(),
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: z.string(),
});

export const serverEnv = {
    DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    NEXTAUTH_SECRET: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    NEXTAUTH_URL: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
};
```

However, the `process.env` object is undefined. The only one that has a value is `NODE_ENV` but it isn't any different than the rest of the env variables.

I'm pretty lost on why this is happening. I've looked up this problem, but nothing is coming up. Am I doing something incorrectly?

[image: The env var errors]

Comment: I should mention that when i console log the env variables on the client side, they all appear. It's just the schema validation that seems to be breaking

Comment: try updating the package. I think they've also updated the docs

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the early maintainers and idea people for T3 & Ct3A

So the beating heart of Create T3 App, is NextJS, this is likely just a small issue with how you are implementing the `.env` not aligning with how NextJS is expecting the file.

For a local dev environment the env file should be -> `.env.local`
for more details on how to do environment variables and file structure here are the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables) relevant to this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification, I've been wrestling with this for hours!

Comment: What's the fix exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is like this

```
❌ Invalid environment variables: {
  DISCORD_CLIENT_ID: [ 'Required' ],
  DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET: [ 'Required' ]
}
```

and you're trying out [t3](https://create.t3.gg/). The fix is:

1. Make sure you're Node version is >= 18. To check run `node -v`.
2. During app creation prompt, select "None" for "What authentication provider would you like to use?" question

Comment: This is probably what you need, this helped me. 
The NextAuth.js authentication provider works through discord.
https://create.t3.gg/en/usage/first-steps#authentication